# Node.js + Passport - Unexpected redirect when using Google oauth2

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, passport.js, middleware, next.js

I am building a node.js server using passport middleware. I'm trying to authenticate my users via Google's oauth2.

The authentication process is as follows:

1. User is redirected to `<server>/auth/google`, which uses passport's middleware thus:
   `passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ["profile", "email"] })`
2. The user then receives Google's login page and logins
3. Google then redirects user to `<server>/auth/google/callback`, which uses passport's middleware thus:
   `passport.authenticate("google", { failureRedirect: "/", session: false })`
4. In the end, the user is redirected to `<client>?token=<token>`

I am hosting my project's front-end on Netlify and the back-end on NOW.

Everything works fine when running on localhost, yet when running in production there is an unexpected redirect during step 3, in which the user is redirected to `<server>/auth/google/t?token=<long-token-string>` instead of the path mentioned.

What is the reason behind this redirect? Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Ofek

Answer (score 1):

After reading and debugging `passport.js` and `oauth`, I finally found out what was wrong. **This was a bug in my code.**

I used this in my config file:

```
export const CLIENT_ORIGIN =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
    ? "https://<project-name>.netlify.com"
    : ["http://127.0.0.1:3000", "http://localhost:3000"];
```

So, when running on localhost, setting `callbackURL = CLIENT_ORIGIN[1]` in the StrategyOptions made sense, but when running in production `CLIENT_ORIGIN` received the value `"https://<project-name>.netlify.com"` (a string instead of an array), therefore `CLIENT_ORIGIN[1]` returned the character `"t"`. As a result, the `callbackURL` received the value `"t"`, which caused this unpredicted (and undocumented) redirect.